# Number of function which are discontinuous at all integer points in $[0,11]$

Tags: functions

> Total number of function $f(x)$ which satisfy $(f(x))^2-3f(x)+2=0$ and which
>
> are discontinuous at all integer points in $[0,11]$ also find number of
>
> discontinuous function in all integer points in $(0,11)$ (Given function defined in $[0,11]$)

$\bf{Attempt}$ Factorisation of  $(f(x))^2-3f(x)+2=0\Rightarrow f(x)=1\;,f(x)=2$

For first parts function discontinuous at $x=0,1,2,3,4,5,,6,7,8,10,11$

and in second part function discontinuous at $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,,7,8,9,10$

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by the statement in parenthesis *(Given function defined in $[0,11]$)* . Does it mean the domain is restricted to $[0,11]$ or that it is a subcase of the previous exercise where domain stays $\mathbb R$ but we restrict the number of discontinuities ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First interpretation $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$

Assuming your function is continuous everywhere except at the specified  integer points then $f$ is constant on each of the intervals $(-\infty,0),(0,1),(1,2),\cdots,(10,11),(11,+\infty)$.

Let's call $x_i=i$ for $i\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,11\}$ and $x_{-1}=-\infty$ and $x_{12}=+\infty$.

Since $f$ can take only $2$ values, we are reduced to the following choices.

The value in the interval $(-\infty,0)$ is free to choose, there are $2$ possibilities.

Then because of the discontinuity at $x_n$ we have the following $3$ choices to fix the value of $f$ inside $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and the value $f(x_n)$

- $f$ has the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ but $f(x_n)$ has a different value
- $f$ has not the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and $f(x_n)=f({x_n}^-)$
- $f$ has not the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and $f(x_n)=f({x_n}^+)$

Since there are $12$ such discontinuity points, we have $3^{12}$ choices.

Overall these are $2\times 3^{12}=1062882$ possibilities.

For the second problem, removing two discontinuities should logically leads to $2\times 3^{10}=118098$ possibilities.

---

#### Second interpretation $f$ defined on $[0,11]$

Assuming your function is continuous everywhere except at the specified  integer points then $f$ is constant on each of the intervals $(0,1),(1,2),\cdots,(10,11)$.

Since $f$ can take only $2$ values, we are reduced to the following choices.

The value in the interval $(0,1)$ is free to choose, there are $2$ possibilities.

Then because of the discontinuity at $x_n$ we have the following $3$ choices to fix the value of $f$ inside $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and the value $f(x_n)$

- $f$ has the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ but $f(x_n)$ has a different value
- $f$ has not the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and $f(x_n)=f({x_n}^-)$
- $f$ has not the same value in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ and $f(x_n)=f({x_n}^+)$

Since there are $10$ such intervals $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ for $n\ge 1$, we have $3^{10}$ choices.

We are left with choices for $f(0)$ and $f(11)$, but since $f(0^+)$ and $f(11^-)$ are already fixed, the discontinuity requirement forces $f(0)$ and $f(11)$ to take the other possible value, this is not a choice.

Overall these are $2\times 3^{10}=118098$ possibilities.

For the second problem it can be interpreted as :

- $f$ is continuous in $0$ and $11$ in which case the number of functions is still $2\times 3^{10}$ (values are forced like in the first problem, but this time to be the same, not different).
- or it could mean that we impose no constraint on $f(0)$ nor $f(11)$ so $f$ can be either continuous there, or discontinuous, so we multiply the number of functions by $4$ to get overall $8\times 3^{10}=472392$.

Comment: there are $12$ possible $x_n$ for $n\in\{0,1,..,11\}$ and for each one, $3$ choices of fixing $f((x_n,x_{n+1}))$ and the value $f(x_n)$.

Comment: Corrected the mistake, do you agree now ?

Comment: OK, I asked precisions from OP, but tried to propose a solution for all interpretations anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f$ as $f(x)=1$ if $x\in[2n,2n+1)$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x\in[2n+1,2n+2)$, for $n=0,1,\cdots,5$. Modify the range of $n$ in this definition according to your requirements.